# Does jruby compile down to the same bytecode as a java app? can it be obfuscated then?

Tags: obfuscation, jruby, bytecode

If jruby can run on tomcat, I'm guessing it compiles down to the same bytecode that a regular java web app would?

Does this mean I can use existing obfuscation tools that exist in the java market and use it on a jruby (ruby on rails) web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can compile down to java bytecode (AOT-Compile). Which means you can use an obfuscation tool.

However you can obviously obfuscate only non-public members of your classes, so the potential for obfuscation in a web-application is usually not particulary high.

Comment: does meta-programming cause any issues? like how ruby uses the MethodNotFound to generate activeRecord method calls like: find_user_by_name(...)